# Convergence in distribution: Show $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \mathbb{P} (x^n \in C) \leq \ \mathbb{P}(x \in C) $

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

> Consider random vectors $(x^n), x \in \mathbb{R}^q$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,A,\mathbb{P})$. Show if $x^n   \overset{d}{\rightarrow} x  $, it holds for any closed set $C$ that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \mathbb{P} (x^n \in C) \leq \mathbb{P}(x \in C) $$

*My thoughts:*

So obviously we have to use $x^n   \overset{d}{\rightarrow} x $. So here is the definition of convergence in distribution:

We say that $(x^n) \in \mathbb{R}^q$ converges in distribution to $x \in \mathbb{R}^q$ if for the corresponding distribution functions $F_n$
and $F$, respectively, and for every continuity point $a \in \mathbb{R}^q$ of $F$, it holds that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
F_n(a) = F(a)$ .

And  $C$ closed means that $C^c$ ( complement of $C$ ) is open. Maybe this could be helpful? Maybe we could show $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf \mathbb{P} (x^n \in O) \geq \mathbb{P}(x \in O) $ ( $O$ open set ) to verify the claim above. But how can I show it? And how can I use it to show $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \mathbb{P} (x^n \in C) \leq \mathbb{P}(x \in C) $ ? I know that $C$ is closed if and only if $C^c$ is open. Moreover I know that $\mathbb{P(A)} =  1-\mathbb{P(A^c)} $.  Or do you have another simple idea to solve this exercise?

**Update**: I've almost showed that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf \mathbb{P} (x^n \in O) \geq \mathbb{P}(x \in O) $, can someone explain me why $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf  \mathbb{1}_O(x^n) \geq 1_O(x) $ is true for an open set $O$? 
My assumption that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf \mathbb{P} (x^n \in O) \geq \mathbb{P}(x \in O) $ ( $O$ open ) implies $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \mathbb{P} (x^n \in C) \leq \mathbb{P}(x \in C) $. 
According to a lecture I found : *This follows upon noting that $C$ is closed if and only if $C^c$ is open, and that $\mathbb{P}(C) = 1 − \mathbb{P}(C^c)$*
Can someone explain me this in detail?

Comment: Just to clarify: by $(x^n)$ you mean any ordinary (distributionally convergent) sequence, and the notation has nothing to do with exponentiation?

Comment: Right. has nothing to with exponentiation. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I cleaned up the MathJax code in a number of respects, including proper use of \inf and \sup. Note that the difference between \sup A and sup A is not just that in $\sup A$ you don't see the operator italicized and in $sup A$ you do, but also there is proper spacing, and the spacing depends on context, so, for example, there is less space to the right of $\sup$ in $\sup(A)$ than in $\sup A. \qquad$

Comment: Also, I saw several instances of $\mathbb{R^q}$ and corrected that, writing $\mathbb{R}^q.$ Sometimes I wonder why some people think the former usage could be considered correct.

Comment: By $(x^n)$, do you mean a sequence of random vectors? That object is usually denoted by $(x_n)_n$, where $x_n :\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is a measurable map.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, Michael. Yes, $x^n$ is a sequence of random vectors. This notation is not mine, it is from my lecture. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated part can be regarded as the dual version of the proposition.
For clarity, I state and prove it as follows.

Let $O\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{d}$ be an open subset. Then $\liminf_{n}P\left(\left[X_{n}\in O\right]\right)\geq P\left(\left[X\in O\right]\right)$.

Proof : Let $C=\mathbb{R}^{d}\setminus O$, then $C$ is a closed
set. Note that $\mu_{n}(O)=1-\mu_{n}(C)$ and $\mu(O)=1-\mu(C)$.
We have that: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\liminf_{n}\mu_{n}(O) & = & \liminf_{n}\left(1-\mu_{n}(C)\right)\\
 & = & 1+\liminf_{n}\left(-\mu_{n}(C)\right)\\
 & = & 1-\limsup_{n}\mu_{n}(C)\\
 & \geq & 1-\mu(C)\\
 & = & \mu(O).
\end{eqnarray*}
That is, $\liminf_{n}P\left(\left[X_{n}\in O\right]\right)\geq P\left(\left[X\in O\right]\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu_{n}$ be the probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^{d},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{d}))$
induced by the random vector $X_{n}$. That is, $\mu_{n}(A)=P\left(X_{n}^{-1}(A)\right)$,
$A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. Let $\mu$ be the probability
measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ induced by $X$. Recall one equivalent
definition of convergence in distribution: $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ in
distribution $\iff$ For each bounded continuous function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$\int\phi\,d\mu_{n}\rightarrow\int\phi\,d\mu$.

Let $C$ be a non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. For each
$m\in\mathbb{N}$, define $U_{m}=\cup\{B(x,\frac{1}{m})\mid x\in C\}$,
where $B(x,r)$ denotes the open ball centered at $x$ with radius
$r$. Note that $U_{m}$ is open, $U_{1}\supseteq U_{2}\supseteq\ldots\supseteq C$
and $C=\cap U_{m}$. (It follows from the well-known property that
for any non-empty closed set $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $x\notin C$,
$d(x,C)=\inf\{d(x,y)\mid y\in C\}>0.$ For, there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ in $C$ such that $d(x,y_n)\rightarrow d(x,C)$. Clearly $(y_n)$ is bounded. Choose a convergent subsequence $(y_{n_k})$ such that $y_{n_k}\rightarrow y$ for some $y$. Since $C$ is closed, we have $y\in C$. It follows that $d(x,C)=d(x,y)>0$.) Apply Urysohn Lemma on the
pair $(C,U_{m})$, we obtain a continuous function $\phi_{m}:\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow[0,1]$
such that $\phi_{m}=1$ on $C$ and $\phi_m=0$ on $(U_m)^c$. Clearly $\chi_{C}\leq\phi_{m}$ and $\phi_{m}\rightarrow\chi_{C}$
pointwisely. We remark that $\phi_{m}$ is bounded continuous and
hence $\lim_{n}\int\phi_{m}\,d\mu_{n}=\int\phi_{m}\,d\mu$.

For any $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
\int\phi_{m}\,d\mu_{n}\geq\int\chi_{C}\,d\mu_{n}.
$$
Taking $\limsup_{n}$ on both sides yields 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\phi_{m}\,d\mu & = & \lim_{n}\int\phi_{m}\,d\mu_{n}\\
 & \geq & \limsup_{n}\int\chi_{C}\,d\mu_{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now let $m\rightarrow\infty$, by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem,
then we have $\int\chi_{C}\,d\mu\geq\limsup_{n}\int\chi_{C}\,d\mu_{n}$.
That is, $\limsup_{n}P\left(\left[X_{n}\in C\right]\right)\leq P\left(\left[X\in C\right]\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I understand your solution. The Urysohn Lemma was new to me. Nevertheless I've updated my question, because my assumptions seem correct.